# Maven skip generating reports when executing Maven build

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, maven-site-plugin

I have several reporting plugins defined in the project and when I do Maven → build fails with `FileNotFoundException` as the reports are cleared when I do Maven → clean. Is there a way to ignore reports when doing Maven build so that build passes without any issue? I tried using Surefire plugin but not luck.

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>${maven-site-plugin.skip}</skip>
    <skipDeploy>true</skipDeploy>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
  <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please add the part of the build output with the complete error message. (Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52971043/edit) link to the left below your question.) Please also add the "_**several** reporting plugins_" configurations. ATM there's only one.

Answer (score 0):

For maven-surefire
add after version

```
<configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the fix for this now. I updated selenium version to 3.14 and I see no issue when building the project